# Angular2: I am getting following error, while installing npm package

Tags: angular

I am new in Angular2. Trying to install package json component using npm install command. After installation, I get following error.

[image]

Because of this error, I am unable to compile my application. It gives more than 100 compilation errors. The errors like below

> `Error 171 '(' expected.   project directory\node_modules\rxjs\operator\concat.d.ts`
>
> `Error 289 Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators'  project directory agGridNg2.ngfactory.ts`

Comment: Can you add your package json content here? at least `dependencies`, `devDependencies` and `peerDependencies`

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.1.0",
    "angular2-text-mask": "2.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "pdfmake": "^0.1.24",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25"
  },

Comment: I am adding some dependencies only due to max length

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `tsconfig.json` set the `experimentalDecorators` to `true`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
  }
}
```